# Android studio / import "shorthand"

Tags: android, android-studio

is there anyway to replace this

```
import com.example.app.R;
```

with

```
import {applicationID}.R;
```

I have given up using flavours (other SO question) but I am now very close where all i need to do is to move files in different folders and I am good to go. Only code change I need to do manually is the above each time (in most of my java files) I change the app "flavour". I am tring to make this process as fast as possible, so i better can manage a higher number of apps hat use the same codebase.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to change the import statement of R.java. The package name of the R file is based on the package atribute value in your manifest file and not on the value of applicationId in your build.gradle file.

Comment: When I drop in and replace the manifest file with another app that has another pakcage name, the old import is of course wrong. So where the java files states import com.example1.app.R; it should now state import com.example2.app.R; or it gives compiler error